# getting error :Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am working on react typescript project,when i try to use `useEffect` function, i am getting this error `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function`, here i have uploaded my whole code, can anyone please look into it and help me to resolve this issue, any help will be really appreciated.

```
import { Redirect, RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { GameDataStore, GameDataStorePayload } from "../../Global/DataStore/GameDataStore";
import { UserData, UserDataStore } from "../../Global/DataStore/UserDataStore";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ContainerProgress } from "../../UI/ContainerProgress";
import { LoadingButton } from "../../UI/LoadingButton";
import { Support } from "./Components/Gameplay/Support";
import { GameChatFab } from "./Components/Chat/GameChatFab";
import { ChatSidebar } from "./Components/Chat/ChatSidebar";
import { GameInner } from "./Components/Gameplay/GameInner";
import { SocketDataStore, SocketDataStorePayload } from "../../Global/DataStore/SocketDataStore";
import moment from "moment";
import { getTrueRoundsToWin } from "../../Global/Utils/GameUtils";
import { ClientGameItem } from "../../Global/Platform/Contract";
import { PlayerJoinApproval } from "@Areas/Game/Components/Gameplay/PlayerJoinApproval";

interface IGameParams {
    id: string;
}

interface IGameState {
    socketData: SocketDataStorePayload;
    gameData: GameDataStorePayload;
    userData: UserData;
    restartLoading: boolean;
    restartDelayed: boolean;
    showSupport: boolean;
    chatDrawerOpen: boolean;
    isFirstTime: boolean;
    total: any;
}

class Game extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<IGameParams>, IGameState>
{
    private supportDelayTimeout = 0;
    public interval;

    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<IGameParams>) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            socketData: SocketDataStore.state,
            gameData: GameDataStore.state,
            userData: UserDataStore.state,
            restartLoading: false,
            restartDelayed: true,
            showSupport: false,
            chatDrawerOpen: true,
            isFirstTime: false,
            total: 0,
        };
    }

    public componentDidMount(): void {
        GameDataStore.hydrate(this.props.match.params.id);

        SocketDataStore.listen(data => this.setState({
            socketData: data
        }));

        GameDataStore.listen(data => this.setState({
            gameData: data
        }));

        UserDataStore.listen(data => this.setState({
            userData: data
        }));


        if (this.state.gameData.game?.started || this.state.gameData.game == null) {

            console.log("socket data");
            console.log(this.state.socketData);
            

            if(this.state.socketData.gamePayload?.chooserGuid == this.state.userData.playerGuid) {
                this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                    this.setState(({ total }) => {
                        return { total: total + 1 };
                    });
                    if (this.state.total == 20) {
                        this.getUpdate();
                        clearInterval(this.interval);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            if(this.state.socketData.gamePayload?.chooserGuid == this.state.userData.playerGuid) {
                this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                    this.setState(({ total }) => {
                        return { total: total + 1 };
                    });
                    if (this.state.total == 20) {
                        this.getUpdate();
                        clearInterval(this.interval);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }   
        });

        
    }



    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    private getUpdate = () => {
        let game_id = this.state.socketData.gamePayload?.id;
        let chooserGuid = this.state.socketData.gamePayload?.chooserGuid;
        let all_players = this.state.socketData.gamePayload?.players;
        if(typeof all_players != undefined && all_players !=null) {
            let all_player_id = Object.keys(all_players);
            let filteredAry = all_player_id.filter(e => e !== this.state.userData.playerGuid);
            let target_item: any = filteredAry.find((_, i, ar) => Math.random() < 1 / (ar.length - i));
            if( (typeof game_id !=undefined && game_id!=null) && (typeof chooserGuid!=undefined && chooserGuid!=null)) {
                return GameDataStore.skipPlayer(game_id, target_item, chooserGuid);
            }
        } 
    }



    private getWinnerFromState(state: IGameState) {
        const {
            players,
            settings
        } = state.gameData.game ?? {};

        const playerGuids = Object.keys(players ?? {});
        const roundsToWin = getTrueRoundsToWin(state.gameData.game as ClientGameItem);
        const winnerGuid = playerGuids.find(pg => (players?.[pg].wins ?? 0) >= roundsToWin);
        return winnerGuid;
    }

    public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<RouteComponentProps<IGameParams>>, prevState: Readonly<IGameState>, snapshot?: any): void {
        const hadWinner = this.getWinnerFromState(prevState);
        const hasWinner = this.getWinnerFromState(this.state);
        if (!hadWinner && hasWinner && this.supportDelayTimeout === 0) {
            this.supportDelayTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    restartDelayed: true,
                    showSupport: true
                });

                setTimeout(() => this.setState({
                    restartDelayed: false
                }), 5000);

            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    private restartClick = (playerGuid: string) => {
        this.setState({
            restartLoading: true
        });

        GameDataStore.restart(playerGuid)
            .finally(() => this.setState({
                restartLoading: false
            }));
    };

    public render() {

        



        const {
            id,
        } = this.props.match.params;

        if (!id) {
            return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
        }

        const {
            dateCreated,
            ownerGuid,
            spectators,
            pendingPlayers,
            players,
            settings,
        } = this.state.gameData.game ?? {};

        if (!this.state.gameData.game || !this.state.gameData.loaded || !this.state.socketData.hasConnection) {
            return <ContainerProgress />;
        }

        const {
            playerGuid
        } = this.state.userData;

        const owner = players?.[ownerGuid ?? ""];
        const amInGame = playerGuid in (players ?? {});
        const amSpectating = playerGuid in { ...(spectators ?? {}), ...(pendingPlayers ?? {}) };
        const title = `${unescape(owner?.nickname ?? "")}'s game`;

        const playerGuids = Object.keys(players ?? {});
        const roundsToWin = getTrueRoundsToWin(this.state.gameData.game as ClientGameItem);
        const winnerGuid = playerGuids.find(pg => (players?.[pg].wins ?? 0) >= roundsToWin);
        const canChat = (amInGame || amSpectating) && moment(dateCreated).isAfter(moment(new Date(1589260798170)));


        return (
            <>
                <Helmet>
                    <title>{title}</title>
                </Helmet>
                <PlayerJoinApproval />
                Timer={this.state.total}
                <GameInner gameId={id} />
                {winnerGuid && (
                    <Dialog open={this.state.showSupport} onClose={() => this.setState({ showSupport: false })}>
                        <DialogContent style={{ padding: "2rem" }}>
                            <Typography variant={"h6"} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                                Game over! {unescape(players?.[winnerGuid].nickname ?? "")} is the winner.
                            </Typography>

                            <Support />

                            {playerGuid === ownerGuid && (
                                <div style={{
                                    marginTop: "7rem",
                                    textAlign: "center"
                                }}>
                                    <LoadingButton loading={this.state.restartLoading || this.state.restartDelayed} variant={"contained"} color={"secondary"} onClick={() => this.restartClick(playerGuid)}>
                                        Restart this game?
                                    </LoadingButton>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </DialogContent>
                    </Dialog>
                )}
                {canChat && (
                    <>
                        <GameChatFab showChat={amInGame || amSpectating} />
                        <ChatSidebar />
                    </>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
};

export default withRouter(Game);
```

Comment: Is that really the complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up, you have `useEffect` within a class component, where **hooks are only for function components**.

Read about [Timing of effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects) to simulate the behavior in class component.

> Unlike `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, the function passed to `useEffect` fires after layout and paint, during a deferred event. This makes it suitable for the many common side effects, like setting up subscriptions and event handlers because most types of work shouldn’t block the browser from updating the screen.

Something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
  if(prevState.socketData.gamePayload?.chooserGuid === prevState.userData.playerGuid) {
     ... }
}
```

Comment: how can we do with class component ?

Comment: You can google "useEffect in class", or read about lifecycles, you can also use `componentWillReceiveProps`